# How to fix fatal error in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I found a system that can generate a report I would like to study this system but when I try to generate the system the login was OK but when I put the password and username this error comes out:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\inventory\db.php on line 8

Can anyone else tell me what is the problem in this system?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek34M.png)

I'm currently using  XAMPP V3.2.2

Comment: you forget to include the database. insert it in your mysqli_connect()

Comment: Please don't insert text as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP 7 within your XAMPP then it wont work because that code is too old. mysql_select_db was removed in PHP 7.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

You will need to install PHP 5 to use that software.

**Edit:** Pratik Solanki is correct also. The database is being connected using mysqli so depending on the other code in the system you can either change the database connect statement to mysql_connect and use PHP 5 (old mysql connector **not recommended**) or change all the database statements to use mysqli instead in which case no PHP changes are needed (**recommended**)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the database while connecting using mysqli_connect function.
In your code, you declared a $mysql_database but you didn't use that.

Code:

```
<php 
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "liveedit";

$bd = mysqli_connect ($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database) or die ("Opps something went wrong ");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You connected to database via **mysqli** module of php and you are trying to select your database via **mysql** module of php.

Correct way to use it would be like this :

```
mysqli_connect(dbhostname,dbusername,dbpassword,dbname)
```

mysqli can be used with the mysql native drivers and mysql can be used via the default libraries provided.

Both are different and the only small mistake you made was making connection with mysqli and selecting db with mysql.

Solution to this is making the whole connection along with selection of db via mysqli function